# Rails : could not identify an equality operator for type json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

i've some problem when triggered some query to sorted `filtered plays data` based on their owner username or `user username`, and i think i've implemeted the right query based on Rails API/Documentation.

the error said : 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`

```
filtered_plays.
  where('plays.user_id = (:id) OR plays.user_id in (:current_friend_ids)', id: id, current_friend_ids: (user_friends + user_friend_users).pluck(:id)).
  union(friend_of_friend_plays).not_flagged.
  joins(:votes).where(votes: { user_id: id }).
  following_prioritized.includes(:user).
  references(:users).sorted_username_ascendingly.
  distinct.
  limit(25)
```

i'll really appreciate any kind of help

Comment: it looks like you try to join on equality of json columns - is `votes.user_id` or `'id` json?.. can you show "translated" resulting query?..

Comment: i think, it's should be `votes.user_id` because only `voted plays` is shown and `plays` has many `votes`. 

did you mean result from above query, sir @VaoTsun ?

Comment: I meant SQL generated please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/7bc0b090108b00c3bab25bebffb40215.git , here you go sir

Comment: hm - I dont see obvious json there - share the tables structure?..

Comment: Sure, sir https://gist.github.com/f75ce14cfa4922df5996e48cd1b622f9.git

Comment: maybe its how you pass values to prepared statement?.. the only json column is not compared anywhere in sql